# OpenERP 7 many2one with current month filter

Tags: python, xml, odoo

here is my festival model class.

```
class festival_registration(osv.osv):
    _name = "bpl.festival"
    _description = "Festivals"
    _columns = {
        'relegious_places_id': fields.many2one('bpl.relegious.places', 'Religious Places'),
        'name': fields.char('Name', size=256, required=True, help='Festival Name'),
        'fest_allowance': fields.float('Advance', size=64, required=True, help='Advance Amount'),
        'installments': fields.integer('Installments', size=32, required=True, help='Number of Installments Installment'),
        'month':fields.selection([('1', 'January'), ('2', 'February'), ('3', 'March'), ('4', 'April'),
            ('5', 'May'), ('6', 'June'), ('7', 'July'), ('8', 'August'), ('9', 'September'),
            ('10', 'October'), ('11', 'November'), ('12', 'December')], 'Month'),

    }
festival_registration()
```

i need to get festivals in my another form for give **festival advances**. then i need to filter that records and **need to show only festivals related to current month** 
how to add domain filter for this requirement or please advice me to sort out this issue by another technique

thanks

here shows my view xml of another model class

```
<record model="ir.ui.view" id="bpl_religion_registration_form">
<field name="name">bpl.relegious.places.form</field>
<field name="model">bpl.relegious.places</field>
<field name="type">form</field>
<field name="arch" type="xml">
<form string="bpl_religion_registration" version='7.0'>
<sheet>
<group>
    <group>
        <field name="religion_id" style="width: 80%%" />
        <field name="relegious_place" style="width: 80%%" />
    </group>
</group>
<div name="Other Info"></div>
<notebook>
    <page string=" Festivals">
        <field name='festival_id' nolabel='1'>
            <tree string='List' editable='bottom'>
                <field name='name' />
                <field name='fest_allowance' />
                <field name='installments' />
                <field name='month' />  .....
```

and here is that another model class which is going to refer festival class

```
class festival_advance(osv.osv):
    _name = "bpl.festival.advance"
    _description = "Festival Advance"
    _columns = {
        'bpl_company_id':fields.many2one('res.company', 'Company', help='Company'),
        'bpl_estate_id':fields.many2one('bpl.estate.n.registration', 'Estate', help='Estate', required=True),
        'bpl_division_id':fields.many2one('bpl.division.n.registration', 'Division', help='Division', domain="[('estate_id','=',bpl_estate_id)]", required=True),
        'festival_id': fields.many2one('bpl.festival', 'Festival' **NEED TO ADD FILTER HERE TO GET CURRENT MONTH FESTIVALS**),
        'festival_advance': fields.float('Amount'),
        'installment': fields.integer('Installment'),
        'festival_advance_ids': fields.one2many('bpl.festival.advance.register', 'festival_advance_id', 'Festival Advances'),
    }
```

and here shows the screen snapshot for more easeness

[image: refer this image]
    festival_advance()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try by adding this domain on the festival field [('month','=',time.strftime('%m'))]. It should work and display all the festivals which are coming in the current month.

Answer (score 0):

thanks Priyesh.
its Done with following code

```
<field name='festival_id' on_change="on_change_festival(bpl_division_id,festival_id)"
domain="[('month','=',time.strftime('%%m'))]" />
```